# New Canon T6i vs used 5D2 or 1Ds3

Tags: canon, equipment-recommendation

The title pretty much states my question here. I've held a T6i (very smooth feeling, good autofocus) and a 5D2 (definitely higher build quality, a full-frame which I would prefer). Never held a 1Ds3 but I did get an opportunity to play with a 1D2 and it felt old and clunky, although well built.

I'm not too concerned about video quality, or even whether video is possible - I don't shoot video seriously whatsoever. I do enjoy good resolution (20MP or above seems to be comfortable) and subject tracking/AF during continuous fire. I'm also definitely going for a Canon since I can adapt my dad's professional M42 lenses - no AE/AF but buying new lenses that cover the same breadth of focal lengths would cost thousands.

I was leaning towards the 5D2 for it's full-frame sensor and high ISO capability and current price point. However, a recent trip to a camera shop where I got to play with a T6i and a 1D2 made me reconsider - the T6i focused much faster, and the 1D2 definitely felt like I would damage the floor more than the camera if dropped. I don't have a particular area of photography I'm interested in, but I'd like the camera to *last* and take high quality images. What's a good choice here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as without knowing better what type of photography you would like to focus on, the answer to this question is anybody's guess. Unless you are prone to dropping things, any of those bodies will take high quality images and last. No one here can make the decision for you.

Comment: I see the previous post, funny it didn't show up in the sidebar while I was typing this up.

I wouldn't consider myself prone to dropping, and I'd say I've never found a particular niche that interests me. There's just a lot of considerations to make for reasonably large purchase like this. Based on the link I'm thinking I'll go with a used professional model. I'll mark it as a dupe.

Comment: Note that the 1Ds Mark III is at least 1.5 generations newer technology than the 1D Mark II. It was released 3.5 years after the the 1D Mark II, almost a year after the 1D Mark III, and 2 years  before the 1D Mark IV.

Answer (score 0):

I have the T4i and the 7Dii. I was going to get the 5Diii but got the 7Dii instead as it was the crop factor version of the 1Dx (as far as I was able to determine). There was a few features that I used all the time that I would have had to buy Add-Ons to get the 5Diii. The 7Dii gave those add-ons natively and with the 2k i saved, I also got the 24-70 f2.8. I know I gave up full frame but I really haven't noticed as the 7Dii has been a really reliable body.

The best suggestion I can suggest is to look at the pro's and cons of each camera you are considering before settling on a body.

Comment: Do you feel like the 7Dii being newer makes it particularly better, or could you have found those features on other older cameras? How is the image quality compared to your T4i?

Comment: The difference between $1,500 US for the 7D II and $2,500 US for the 5D III (which is what both of these cameras are currently selling for from reputable dealers in the U.S.) is $1K, not $2K.

Comment: @gjsmo I found the features existed on the T4i that i used also existed on the 7Dii.

Comment: @MichaelClark Sorry, that was ~2k CAD. I am Canadian.

Comment: The difference is only $1.4K CAD at amazon.ca

Comment: I was going based on when I bought it, back Dec 2014.